# Разметка (партитура) стихотворения. Правильно я сделала?

Tags: литература

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверьте, пожалуйста,правильно я сделала?

Comment: Разместите формулировку вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения.

Answer (score 2):

У каждого свои интонации, я бы прочитала совсем по-другому. Вот неплохое чтение, сравните.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwBBE2zM--U  По-моему, там в одной строке повышение и понижение голоса.